# error in Compilation typescript for vs code

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I get this error when I try to compile the typescript file

```
tsc : File C:\Users\emanull\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
PS C:\Users\emanull\Desktop\backend> tsc main.ts
tsc : File C:\Users\emanull\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see     
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc main.ts
+ ~~~        
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your Powershell as administrator and run this command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```